# How to use an object property as a function argument?

Tags: javascript, function, oop

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to vadim. I had to change `months[i].anArray[b]` to `months[i][anArray][b]`

I have an array of months, which contains an object for each month. Each month has a number of properties, including arrays, for example:

`months[0].consumptionPerHour` returns 24 values which can be accessed with `months[0].consumptionPerHour[0-23]`

I am attempting to create a function which creates a table, having the name of the table and the name of the array I wish to access as arguments with the function, like so:

```
function tableMaker(tableName, anArray) {
  $("#outputs").append(
    "<table id='table" + totalTables + "'>"
    "<tr id='header" + totalTables + "'><td>" + tableName + "</td>"
  );
  for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
    $("#header" + totalTables).append("<td>" + months[i].shortName + "</td>");
  }
  for(b=0;b<24;b++) {
    $("#table" + totalTables).append(
      "<tr id='table" + totalTables + "row" + b + "'><td>" + hours[b] + "</td>"
    );
    for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
      $("#table" + totalTables + "row" + b).append("<td>" + months[i].anArray[b] + "</td>");
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, if I pass a property name  that I know exists as an argument, for example, `tableMaker('Consumption', consumptionPerHour)`, it simply returns the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: consumptionPerHour is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:22
```

However, this is returned via console:

```
months[0].consumptionPerHour
(24) [0.1567002086212712, 0.1567118400503239, ...]

months[0].consumptionPerHour[0]
0.1567002086212712
```

Comment: There is no reference to any `consumptionPerHour` in the code shown. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: Thanks, I've done that.

Comment: Ok... you are referring to it as a variable but that variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Your statement should be `tableMaker('Consumption', 'consumptionPerHour')`, I think you need to pass the string `'consumptionPerHour'` instead of variable.

Comment: If you have object months with given property consumptionPerHour you can access it like month[0]['consumptionPerHour'] and if you pass propertyName as argument you can use it like month[0][propertyName]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an object property using a variable you need to use `[]` notation and the variable needs to be a string

So *I think* what you want is

```
tableMaker('Consumption', 'consumptionPerHour')
```

Then in function use:

```
months[i][anArray][b]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'consumptionPerHour' is an array within the 'months' array. And it also looks like you have access to the months array in the function without having to pass it in as a parameter. So the function would look something like this:

```
function tableMaker(tableName) {
  $("#outputs").append(
    "<table id='table" + totalTables + "'>"
    "<tr id='header" + totalTables + "'><td>" + tableName + "</td>"
  );
  for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
    $("#header" + totalTables).append("<td>" + months[i].shortName + "</td>");
  }
  for(b=0;b<24;b++) {
    $("#table" + totalTables).append(
      "<tr id='table" + totalTables + "row" + b + "'><td>" + hours[b] + "</td>"
    );
    for(i=0;i<12;i++) {
      $("#table" + totalTables + "row" + b).append("<td>" + months[i].consumptionPerHour[b] + "</td>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea of the function was to generate a table based on both an array and the name of the table itself. The objects in `months` have many arrays, each of which I wished to create a table for.

Comment: Can you post what the structure of the data/variables look like?  I think you can do what you are trying to do but need to see how the variables are structured.